# ModSecurity Ratelimiting Login Failures

Tags: apache, mod-security

I am trying to build a rule to limit the number of xmlrpc.php authentication failures to 5 per minute. The ModSecurity rules I have so far are:

```
SecAction phase:1,nolog,pass,initcol:IP=%{REMOTE_ADDR},id:690010
<LocationMatch "/xmlrpc.php">
SecRule IP:COUNTXYZ "@gt 5" "phase:1,deny,status:403,log,msg:'WAF Rules : IP address blocked - more than 5 xmlrpc errors in 60 seconds',id:690011"
SecRule RESPONSE_BODY "faultCode" "phase:4,pass,nolog,setvar:ip.countxyz=+1,deprecatevar:ip.countxyz=1/60,id:690012"
</LocationMatch>
```

Despite repeated calls to site on this server using:

```
curl -d '<?xml version="1.0"?> <methodCall> <methodName>wp.getUsersBlogs</methodName> <params> <param> <value>username</value> </param> <param> <value>password</value> </param> </params> </methodCall>' http://victimsite/xmlrpc.php
```

which in each case sends back a body containing the text 'faultCode' - but it never blocks the requests, even though each request comes from a fixed IP address. Is there a problem in my rules syntax, or is there a way i can debug this?

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need slash in Locationmatch "/xmlrpc.php"
- You probably need 'SecResponseBodyAccess On' in Location block or equivalent in chain
  before trying to inspect RESPONSE_BODY

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution turned out to be:

```
SecAction phase:1,nolog,pass,initcol:IP=%{REMOTE_ADDR},id:690010     
<LocationMatch "/xmlrpc(\.php)?$">
SecAction phase:2,nolog,pass,deprecatevar:ip.count_a=1/20,id:690010
SecRule IP:COUNT_A "@gt 5" "phase:2,deny,status:403,log,msg:'WAF Rules : XMLRPC - Ratelimited to one call in 20 seconds',id:690012"
SecRule RESPONSE_BODY "fault(Code|String)" "phase:4,pass,nolog,setvar:ip.count_a=+1,id:690013"
</LocationMatch>
```